# Deadlock on queue.pop - Ruby

Tags: ruby

This results in a: deadlock detected (fatal) error

```
require 'thread'

@queue = Queue.new
x = @queue.pop
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

From [Ruby documentation for Queue#pop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html#method-i-pop):

> Retrieves data from the queue. If the queue is empty, the calling thread is suspended until data is pushed onto the queue. If non_block is true, the thread isn’t suspended, and an exception is raised.

You are working with a single thread here so your queue never contains any objects, therefore your thread gets suspended forever (deadlocked).

Try this instead

```
require "thread"

queue = Queue.new
thread1 = Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    x = queue.pop
    sleep rand(i) # simulate workload
    puts "taken #{x} from queue!"
  end
end

thread2 = Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    sleep rand(i) # simulate workload
    queue.push i
    puts "pushed #{i} to the queue!"
  end
end

thread1.join
```

You have two threads now, so you will not experience a deadlock. The consumer thread will get suspended when the queue is empty, but it will become active again when the second thread pushes something to the queue.